# Apache/htaccess - password protect a site by domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, password, password-protected

Is it posible to protect a website if the site was called by a given domain name?

e.g.

```
www.domain.com -> no password protection
www.domain.net -> password protection
```

Both of the URLs are routed to the same document root.

Comment: I found this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068975/domain-name-specific-code-blocks-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple virtualhosts, you can add password protection to one and not the other via the following directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example1.org
<Directory "/www/example1">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Site"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/passwd
Require user joeuser
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is more information on this:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html